# Plot eigenvalues of matrix as function of matrix element

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, eigenvalue

I have never used python before, but need it now because I'm working on a colleague's project. I want to plot the eigenvalues of a matrix as a function of an element of the matrix, i.e. my matrix looks like

```
    M=[[40,0,4],[0,0,4],[4,4,x]]
```

where x is a variable. So the matrix has three eigenvalues

```
    eig=numpy.linalg.eigvals(M)
    eig1=eig[0]
    eig2=eig[1]
    eig3=eig[0]
```

But how can I plot this as a function of x? Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is many ways to loop over the values of `x` you are interested in. You could do an explicit `for` loop, or you can use a list comprehension. In the example below I compute a 2-d array with 3 columns, one for each eigenvalue. The number of rows is the number of `x` values we are using.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = np.linspace(0,100,101)   # consider x values 0, 1, .., 100
eigenvalues = np.array([np.sort(np.linalg.eigvals([[40,0,4],[0,0,4],[4,4,x]])) for x in xx])

plt.plot(xx, eigenvalues[:,2],label="largest")
plt.plot(xx, eigenvalues[:,1],label="medium")
plt.plot(xx, eigenvalues[:,0],label="smallest")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

gives

[image]